# Android Facebook SDK Bug

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, webview

I have an app that uses Facebook SDK with some permissions.
Usually, when a user presses the LOGIN button, the app opens Facebook App or a Webview (depending on wheather Facebook app is installed) and asks the user to authorize my app.
However, on some devices WITH the Facebook app, the SDK skips the authorization process and thus making my app get stuck.

I call the authorization method like this:

```
mFacebook.authorize(mContext, PERMISSIONS, new DialogListener() {bla bla};
```

Where PERMISSIONS is a String Array.
I found out that if I uninstall the Facebook app, everything works just fine using Webview...

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you ever gotten a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can happen if the user is already logged in  on the device (maybe from another app). The facebook app implements Single Sign On. You can find more details and code here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/#sso

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the case, because SSO is for sparing the user from typing username & password for each app, but it should always ask for permissions for a NEW app. Anyway, my code is exactly as shown in your link...